# Is there a way to add business specific metadata to be stored along with audio file stored on google cloud via google cloud speech logging?

Tags: go, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-speech

We are working on integrating with google cloud speech for speech to text conversion with logging enabled. When the audio files are logged we also need to store an additional Identifier stored with the audio file so that later on when we retrieve the audio file from google cloud we can perform entity to audio file association. Is that possible? Can we store user provided metadata along with the audio file? We are going to stream audio data for conversion and we need to store the audio file + some metadata supplied by us.

Comment: Hello and welcome! You might want to read [How do I ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), which enhances the probability for getting a useful answer _drastically_. You might find [ESR](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eric_S._Raymond)'s excellent essay [How To Ask Questions The Smart Way](http://catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html) helpful, too - despite it's harsh title.

Answer (score 0):

[Data logging](https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/data-logging) is only a way to send your data anonymously to Google to help improve the Speech API, there is no metadata that can be used here. The accessible metadata associated with samples only comprises the samples audio properties, passed in to the API  through the [`RecognitionConfig` object](https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/reference/rest/v1beta1/RecognitionConfig).

Provided that you store your samples in Cloud Storage, you can use [the bucket URI’s to process sample requests](https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/basics#uri-audio), or the [Cloud Storage client library](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/reference/libraries) to retrieve the samples with their unique filename.